# Transferring Data from a vector to a queue and off

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I have a block a legacy code that I am trying to implement a queue for. Overall I have a message receiver function in my class that does the following:

```
 void RCVER::receiveMessage(const std::vector<char> &incomingMessage) {
      int size = incomingMessage.size();
      msgQ.push(incomingMessage); 
      std::cout << "Received msg of size: " << size << std::endl; //THIS IS GOOD
      for(size_t i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
      {
         std::cout << incomingMessage[i] << std::endl; //DATA IS GOOD HERE
      }
  }
```

Where msgQ is defined in the header as:

`std::queue< std::vector <char> > msgQ;`

Later in my processing chain I then try to pop the data that I pushed onto the queue, to eventually be sent out via a TCP/IP connection. The code is as follows:

```
void RCVER::getMessage(const char* data, int &bytes)
{
  std::vector<char> tmp;
  if(!msgQ.empty())
  {
    tmp = msgQ.front();
    bytes = tmp.size();
    data = &tmp[0];
    msgQ.pop();
    std::cout << "Pulled msg of size: " << bytes << " off of the queue." << std::endl; //THIS IS GOOD
    if(DEBUG)
    {
       for(size_t i = 0; i < bytes-1; i++)
       {
          std::cout << data[i] << std::endl; //NOT GOOD - PRINTS BLANK LINES
       }
  }
}
```

My problem is when i turn on the debug flag, I just print blank lines for the size of data. Size is correct. The code then just sends the data that is returned from getMessage to the TCP/IP send call. Is what I am doing incorrect? I cannot really see an issue with the code and would just like another set of eyes on it to see if there is something really wrong with it.

I do NOT have access at the TCP/IP receiver to verify that it is receiving the correct messages.

P.S. the tmp variable in getMessage was a quick fix since I wasn't able to pull the vector from the queue in one line. If someone wants to inform me on a better way to do this, I would be welcome to it!

Also I am not the most savvy coder out there. I would assume doing this with templates would be super easy but I am not familiar with them at all.

Compiling with: gcc4.9.2, on Linux 2.6.32.

Comment: Can you verify the data in the message is valid?  What if it's all 0s?

Comment: I have verified in the receiveMessage that the data is valid.

Comment: And the correct number of bytes is printed in `getMessage`?

Comment: 1. Is there only one entry in your queue? Could it be that your data is elsewhere? 2. Regardless, you are returning a pointer to a local variable from your `RCVER::getMessage`; that will likely cause a crash later on.

Comment: The bytes that are being returned in getMessage are correct as when printing them out. To Vlad's point we are not crashing because there is only one entry in my queue. I guess another point would be again - is there a better way to do this? I do not feel comfortable assuming that there will only ever be one entity in the queue. My solution though would be to loop through this and send out each message until the queue is empty, however, I would like to get this working. Overall - does this code seem correct to you?